# How to avoid Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit in async task

Tags: java, spring, jpa, rollback

I has develop API for integrate file in database in async task. 
I want my entire file processed, and I record every error in the database.

My API call this Service

```
@Service
public class ImportFichier {

    @Async("taskExecutor")
    public void importReference(ImportFichierDTO importFichierDTO,
                                List<Reference> references,
                                Long idEntite,
                                Long currentUserId,
                                boolean update){
        log.debug("Request to importReference pour entite : {}", idEntite);

        for(Reference reference : references) {
            if (update) {
                referentielService.update(idEntite, reference, currentUserId, importFichierDTO.getId());
            } else {
                referentielService.add(idEntite, reference, currentUserId, importFichierDTO.getId());
            }
        }

        // mise à jour de l'heure de fin du traitement d'import
        importFichierDTO.setDateFin(ZonedDateTime.now());
        importFichierService.save(importFichierDTO);

        return;
    }
```

For adding data, treatment call this service :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ReferentielCompteurServiceImpl implements ReferentielCompteurService {
 ....

@Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {CustomException.class, ConstraintViolationException.class})
public Compteur add(Compteur compteur, Long entiteMereId, Long entiteId, Long userId, Long importId) {

    Optional<ArticleEtat> articleEtat = articleEtatRepository.findOneByCode(compteur.getCodeEtat());
    if (!articleEtat.isPresent()) {
        if (importId > 0) {
            importFichierTraceService.add(importId, compteur.getUuidReference().toString(), CustomError.ERROR_ARTICLE_ETAT_NOT_FOUND.getErrorDescription());
            return compteur;
        } else {
            throw new CustomException(CustomError.ERROR_ARTICLE_ETAT_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    ....
    ReferentielCompteurDTO result = save(referentielCompteurDTO, importId);
```

And method "save" in the same service :

```
@Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {CustomException.class, ConstraintViolationException.class})
public ReferentielCompteurDTO save(ReferentielCompteurDTO referentielCompteurDTO, Long importId) {
    log.debug("Request to save ReferentielCompteur : {}", referentielCompteurDTO);

    if (referentielCompteurDTO.getDateCreation() == null) {
        referentielCompteurDTO.setDateCreation(ZonedDateTime.now());
    }
    referentielCompteurDTO.setDateModification(ZonedDateTime.now());

    ReferentielCompteur referentielCompteur = referentielCompteurMapper.toEntity(referentielCompteurDTO);

    try {
        referentielCompteur = referentielCompteurRepository.save(referentielCompteur);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException cve) {
        importFichierTraceService.add(importId, referentielCompteurDTO.getReferenceId().toString(), cve.getMessage());
    }

    return referentielCompteurMapper.toDto(referentielCompteur);
}
```

When I generate a ConstraintViolationException I have this exception :

```
 Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit' and exception = 'Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit'

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:312)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
```

I see several post, but I don't understand how solve this problem, and is it possible

Can you help me please?

Comment: You cannot not rollback on a `ConstraintViolation`. You simply cannot commit illegal data to the database.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are wright.it's stupid of me. I delete  @Transactional(noRollbackFor = {CustomException.class, ConstraintViolationException.class})
 and same result

Comment: Ofcourse you will get the same result. You catch the exception, Spring never sees it, hence thinks everything is ok, tries to commit, but transaction has been marked for rollback. Don't catch the exception.

Comment: If I don't catch the exception, my async task stop.. and the end of file was not treated

Comment: You need to catch it outside of the method, then do the logging in another transaction. Of let the `importFichierTraceService.add` run in a separate transaction (`REQUIRES_NEW`) you need a separate one because the current one isn't valid anymore.

Comment: @M.Deinum I add response with new test

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of M.Deinum, I try :

for importFichierTraceService.add

```
@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)
public void add(Long importId, String line, String message) {
```

I delete @Transactional and catch Exception

```
@Override
public ReferentielCompteurDTO save(ReferentielCompteurDTO referentielCompteurDTO, Long importId) {
```

And add catch Exception in :

```
@Override
public Compteur add(Compteur compteur, Long entiteMereId, Long entiteId, Long userId, Long importId) { 

try {
        result = save(referentielCompteurDTO, importId);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException cve) {
        importFichierTraceService.add(importId, referentielCompteurDTO.getReferenceId().toString(), cve.getMessage());
        return compteur;
    }
```

Result is the same